# Java - Adding items from arraylist to JTable when button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I was trying to write the GUI for my program. I have a Product class in which I store price and names of the products in an arraylist. I also have an Order arraylist which consists of the orders given to each waiter.I put all my products in a JComboBox and added an action listener to each to show the price of each product when clicked by updating the text of a JLable. Then there is a JSpinner to get the quantity of the products selected. And lastly there is an "Add" button that I wanted to use to update the Jtable with product name and its quantity and its total price while also adding that product to the arraylist of Orders. I have no idea how populate JTable and couldn't understand much from other answers because they were using netbeans. I thought of just using a simple JLabe but also I couldn't understand how to update the text and add a new line to the label after I select and add each product. Can you explain how I can achieve this? part of my code looks like this

```
box1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Product prod = (Product) box1.getSelectedItem();
        price.setText(String.valueOf(prod.getSellingPrice()));

        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int numbs = (Integer) spinner.getValue();
                for (int i = 0; i <= numbs; i++) {
                    order.addProduct(prod);
                }
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                lists.add(label);
                label.setText(prod.getName() + " " + numbs + " " + numbs * prod.getSellingPrice());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a JTable in your gui, which shows the orders (or other data possibly) if a button is clicked.

Firstable, I would advise you to check out

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

as they explain the use of the JTable very well.

Anyway, to answer your question:

Firstable, you have to create a table and add it to your gui:

```
//creating a new JTable without any data and one column 'Orders'
//you might wanna declare the JTable before that, since it will be referred to in the refresh() method
JTable table = new JTable(new String[][]{{""}}, new String[]{"Orders"});
//creating a scrollpane to put the table in, in case the table data exeeds the table
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
//here you would e.g. set the bounds of the scrollpane etc
scrollPane.setBounds(x,y,w,h)
//setting the table in the scrollpane
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
//adding the scrollpane to your contentPane
contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

Now you want to refresh the table, if a button is pressed, so I would put a reference to the following method in the actionlistener of the button:

```
//the method to refresh the table containing the orders (or possibly other data)
void refresh(List<String> orders) {
    //creating a new TableModel for the table
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
    //set the data in the model to the data that was given, new Object[]{0} points to the 1st column
    model.setDataVector(getDataVector(data), new Object[]{"Orders});
    //set the model of the table to the model we just created
    table.setModel(model);
}
```

Since `model.setDataVecor()` takes rows and not columns as its first parameter, you have to make the list of data fitting as a data vector, for example with the following method:

```
Object[][] getDataVector(List<String> data){
    Object[][] vector = new Object[data.size()][1];
    for(int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
        vector[i][0] = data.get(i);
    }
    return vector;
 }
```

Comment: You should NOT invoke `fireTableDataChanged()`. It is the responsibility of the TableModel to invoke that method.

Comment: How so? @camickr

Comment: You should NOT invoke any of the fireXXX(….) methods from your application code. If you invoke a method on the model, the model will invoke the appropriate method. If you use the setModel(…) method on the table it will recreate the TableColumnModel based on the new model.

Comment: @camickr You are absolutly correct, I edited the code appropriately.